# Custom role provider for SharePoint 2010:

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, roleprovider

I have written both custom Membership and Role providers for SharePoint 2010.  The Membership provider has been working just fine for months.  I just finished the Role provider, added it to the GAC, set it up in Central Admin, and added it to the web configs, etc.

When I fire up SP, I get this error:
Could not load file or assembly 'X' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

What else do I need to do besides adding it to the GAC?  Where could I have gone wrong?

Answer (score 0):

1) Go to project properties.
2) Make sure "Target Framework" is set to ".NET Framework 3.5."
3) Add new assembly to the GAC using "Visual Studio x64 Command Prompt" instead of the regular VS command prompt.